# How read coprocessor registers in ARM architecture

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I'm trying to read CP15 coprocessor in the following System-on-chip

Cortex A7 - ARMv7-A

Below my snippet

```
void main (void)
{
    unsigned int reg_value = 0;
    asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c0, c0, 0" : "=r"(reg_value) );
    printf("reg_value: %d", reg_value);
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to read the coprocessor register but its compilation is completed without errors.
The problem is arisen during its execution (the code is executed in root):

```
Illegal instruction
```

If I use gdb I obtain the following result:

```
   0x000086a0 <+16>:    str r3, [r11, #-40] ; 0x28
=> 0x000086a4 <+20>:    mrc 15, 0, r3, cr0, cr0, {0}
   0x000086a8 <+24>:    str r3, [r11, #-40] ; 0x28
```

Why I'm not able to read coprocessor registers? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you made sure that you are allowed to read this register?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which register are you trying to read (name)?

Comment: Also it looks like you are running it under USR mode. These registers are accessible in privileged modes only (SVC/SYS/IRQ/FIQ/ABT). Running user space application under root is still `USR`.

Comment: I'm trying to read MIDR= Main ID Register. I think i'm working as USR: how can I check it?

Comment: Can you print `$cpsr`?

Comment: This is CPSR taken during gdb debugging: `cpsr 0x600c0010 1611399184`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: correct me if I'm wrong but I'm in USR mode (last five bits equal to 0x10). In which mode I can read those registers? How can I switch to another mode (if it is possible)?

Comment: You are using Linux, as far as I understand, so I don't think you will be able to do it from user space. I would say you will need a kernel module for that.

Comment: Yes, i'm using linux. In the user manual it is written _only accessible from PL1 or higher._ . As far as I know., USR mode is equal to PL0, then I'm not able to read it. Do you know any possible workaround?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to access MIDR: Main ID Register (from the ARMARMv7 B4.1.105) using the instruction

```
MRC p15, 0, <Rt>, c0, c0, 0    ; Read MIDR into Rt
```

However, as you are in Linux and executing an application, you are in usermode (PL0)
and ARMARMv7 specifies in the usage constraints of MIDR that

> Only accessible from PL1 or higher.

So only accessible at PL1, PL2, PL3. To access it you need to create a driver running at PL1 which will do the read of MIDR. Then, in your application, open this driver to get the data using IOCTL for example.

You can also try to access the kernel mode (PL1) using a SVC call from PL0, but this would imply modifying your kernel SVC handler.

Comment: Do you know if a driver able to read ARM coprocessor is already present for linux? Should I write it from scratch?

Comment: I don't think there is a driver present in linux for that. You can maybe have a look to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN121, https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/195-simple-driver-for-linux-os https://github.com/pokitoz/ioctl_driver for a more specific example on how to write one. There are many examples that can be found